# Integrals agree over different sets implies integrands agree.

Tags: measure-theory

I am in a situation where $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, and for every $A \in \Sigma$ I know that $\int_A f = \int_A g$. I know $f,g \in L^1$ are measurable with respect to the larger $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}\supseteq \Sigma$. Can I conclude that $f=g$ (a.e.)?

Certainly if I knew that $g$ was $\Sigma$-measurable, I would be able to subtract and consider integrating over $\{f > g\}$ and over $\{g > f\}$ to conclude that $f=g$. But if I don't know that $g$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, then I wouldn't know that $\{f>g\} \in \Sigma$.

Comment: We say that $f$ is the *conditional expectation* of $g$ with respect to $\Sigma$. (At least when the whole space has measrue 1.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no: take $\Omega:=\{a,b\}$, $\Sigma:=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and $\mathcal A:=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ (same measure on $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$). Let $f$ be constant equal to $1$ and $g=2\chi_{\{a\}}$.